# \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} leads to error: Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }

Tags: errors, pdftex, unicode, languages, input-encodings

I have a problem with `\usepackage[UTF8]{vietnam}`.

```
\documentclass[clock,fragile]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts, mathrsfs,bm,mathpazo}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{multicol,xcolor,animate,multimedia,tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumerate,shadowtext}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,
shapes,decorations.text}
\usepackage{url, picinpar,graphicx,lipsum}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
[place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm,text width=2cm,align=center},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]
\node at ( 0,0) [place] (Ap){Nhóm $ p $ - adic};
\node at ( 4,0) [place] (X){Continuum Peano};
%\node at ( 0,0) [place] {};
\node at ( 8,2.5) [place] (kq1){Phân hoạch đẳng biến};
\node at (8,-2.5) [place] (kq2){Đường cong Menger};
\draw [->] (Ap.east) -- (X.west) node [above,text width=3cm,align=center,midway]{tác động};
\draw [->] (X.north) to [bend left=30] (kq1.west) node [auto,swap]{hiệu} ;
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
\draw [->,line width=1.5pt,color=red,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift| Tự do}}}] (X.south) to [bend right=30] (kq2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After run `pdflatex`, I get `! Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }`. How to fix it?

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Answer (score 8):

The example if fixed by braces around the problematic UTF-8 character inside
the text for `decorate`:

```
text={|\myshift| T{ự} do}
```

Otherwise the text would be scanned byte by byte and disrupting the multi-byte UTF-8 character.